# Bootstrap 3 Multi Item Carousel only showing one item at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I tried to create a multi-item carousel from [here](https://codepen.io/Qvatra/pen/yOvBoM).

Here it looks perfect, as I'd want it to work.
But when I take this code to my workspace, it only shows one item at a time and rest of the place stays empty.
This is how it looks on my machine:

[image: how it looks on my machine]

ideally it should show 4 items at one time and scroll 1 by 1. But it only shows 1 item and the place of other 3 items remains empty.
Can you please suggest what could I be missing here?

```js
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() {
 var next = $(this).next();
 if (!next.length) {
  next = $(this).siblings(':first');
 }
 next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

 for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  next = next.next();
  if (!next.length) {
   next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }

  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
 }
});
```

```css
.col-centered {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-control { 
    width: 8%;
    width: 0px;
}
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right { 
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 32px; 
    background-image: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-control > a > span {
    color: white;
   font-size: 29px !important;
}

.carousel-col { 
    position: relative; 
    min-height: 1px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    float: left;
 }

 .active > div { display:none; }
 .active > div:first-child { display:block; }

/*xs*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right { left: 50%; }
 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
 .carousel-inner .prev       { left: -50%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 50%; }
 .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
}

/*sm*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right { left: 50%; }
 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
 .carousel-inner .prev       { left: -50%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 50%; }
 .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
}

/*md*/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%; }
 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
 .carousel-inner .prev       { left: -33%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 33%; }
 .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div { display:block; }
}

/*lg*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right{ left:  25%; }
 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
 .carousel-inner .prev       { left: -25%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 25%; }
 .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div { display:block; }
 .active > div:first-child + div + div + div { display:block; }
}

.block {
 width: 306px;
 height: 230px;
}

.red {background: red;}

.blue {background: blue;}

.green {background: green;}

.yellow {background: yellow;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
    

</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-10 col-centered">

   <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="2500">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
      <div class="carousel-col">
       <div class="block red img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="carousel-col">
       <div class="block green img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="carousel-col">
       <div class="block blue img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="carousel-col">
       <div class="block yellow img-responsive"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <div class="left carousel-control">
     <a href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="right carousel-control">
     <a href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle

Comment: have you tried to add javascript in `$(document).ready(function(){ })`?